# Building Dashboard to look at Record type, Stage and Record Count

Tags: reporting, dashboard

Quick question

Aim – To create the following below in a standard dashboard

Currently i have a dashboard which looks at the "Stage" and "Record Count" , I am wondering can i also have Record type ?

I have upload the Desired results as a jpeg Image (See below)

[image]

Can i achieve my desired results ?

Looking forward to your help

Regards
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

1. Make sure your source summary report groups by the columns you need (record type and stage).
2. Add a chart to the report (or modify existing one) and include these columns in the chart, for example:

   - X axis: record count
   - Y axis: record type
   - group by: stage
3. On the dashboard edit the component (wrench icon) and decide to customize the table manually. You should get something similar to this:

[image]

As you can see up to 4 columns can be exposed on the dashboard table (one of them has to be a summary column like "record count"). Each has to be used in report grouping and shown on the chart (trick with "plot additional values" might help).